# Python bar chart with duplicate datetimes in index

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I would like to make a barchart in python using matplotlib pyplot. The data consists of an index, which is a datetime list, and a number corresponding to that datetime. I have various samples that all belong to the same day. However, when making the bar chart, it only shows the first samples corresponding to a certain datetime, instead of all of them. How can I make a barchart showing every entry?

The index has the following structure:

```
ind = [datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 0), 
       datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 15, 0, 0)]
```

and the values are just integers:

```
values = [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

So when plotting, it only shows the bars 2017-3-1 with value 10, and 2017-3-15 with value 30. How can I make them show all of them?

Comment: You would plot the `values` against the first n integer numbers `plt.bar(range(len(values)), values)` and set the ticks to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can groupby the dates, add the values and then plot the barchart from the same dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=ind)
df = df.groupby(df.index).sum()
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

If what you want is all values to appear in the plot, regardless of the date, you can simply use:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

And entries with duplicate date will be plotted independently.